# Intellij, how to use last commit message by default?

Tags: intellij-idea

The Intellij commit window does not populate with the last commit message, but seems to use some other logic like saving the message that was there when the commit window was exited prematurely.   Is there a setting to accomplish this?

Comment: I think this is probably deliberate to discourage lazy commit messages. To be honest I'm inclined to agree with their approach, if commit B achieves the same as commit A then they shouldn't be distinct.

Answer (score 1):

In .idea/workspace.xml, change the comment to an empty string, `""`

```
<component name="ChangeListManager">
    <list default="true" id="..." name="Default Changelist" comment="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Local changes` tab right click on your current changelist and choose `Edit changelist`. In edit window popup remove any text in `Comment` input.

Unfortunately this field is set again so problem will reappear after some time.

There is also `Clear initial commit message` setting in `Preferences` / `Version Control` / `Commit`. This way you can have an empty commit message every time you open commit dialog.